# Cannot choose between variants in Kotlin MPP

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have two Kotlin MPP depending on each other Flowchart -> Beans.

"Beans" has two JVM-variants one with the view-attribute set to "javafx" and one without the view-attribute.

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(11)

    jvm()
    jvm("javafx") {
        attributes.attribute(viewAttribute, "javafx")
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val plainMain by creating
        val javafxMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("org.openjfx:javafx-base:$javafxVersion:$javafxPlatform")
                api("org.fxmisc.easybind:easybind:1.0.3")
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependsOn(plainMain)
        }
    }
}
```

"Flowchart" has three JVM-variants.

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(11)

    jvm()

    jvm("swing") {
        attributes.attribute(viewAttribute, "swing")
    }

    jvm("javafx") {
        attributes.attribute(viewAttribute, "javafx")
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("de.fluxparticle:beans:3.3-SNAPSHOT")
            }
        }
        val javafxMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:$javafxVersion:$javafxPlatform")
                api("org.openjfx:javafx-base:$javafxVersion:$javafxPlatform")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first two work fine but the third with the view-attribute set to "javafx" I get this error message:

```
      > The consumer was configured to find an API of a library, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm', attribute 'de.fluxparticle.javis.view' with value 'javafx'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of de.fluxparticle:beans:3.3-SNAPSHOT:
          - javafxApiElements-published
          - javafxRuntimeElements-published
          - jvmApiElements-published
          - jvmRuntimeElements-published
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'javafxApiElements-published' capability de.fluxparticle:beans:3.3-SNAPSHOT declares an API of a library, as well as attribute 'de.fluxparticle.javis.view' with value 'javafx', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides integration status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'javafxRuntimeElements-published' capability de.fluxparticle:beans:3.3-SNAPSHOT declares a runtime of a library, as well as attribute 'de.fluxparticle.javis.view' with value 'javafx', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides integration status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' capability de.fluxparticle:beans:3.3-SNAPSHOT declares an API of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about de.fluxparticle.javis.view (required 'javafx')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides integration status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'jvmRuntimeElements-published' capability de.fluxparticle:beans:3.3-SNAPSHOT declares a runtime of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about de.fluxparticle.javis.view (required 'javafx')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides integration status but the consumer didn't ask for it
```

According to the [algorithm](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm) Gradle should select the "longest" match which should be the one with the correct attribute-value. Why does it not work? Is it because there is an API and RUNTIME variant?

I tried setting the attribute value to "" in "Beans" but then I get the same problem in another variant of "Flowchart".